# What is ~없어서는, how is it used?

Tags: grammar, translation, phrase-meaning

This sentence seemes to say the opposite of what it "should" mean.

> **찬양과 예배의 삶은 신앙인들에게 없어서는 하나님과의 관계이자 생명 그 자체이다**

Just to clarify, I'm not confused (hopefully) on these items:

- `찬양과 예배의 삶은` = a life of praising and worshiping
- `신앙인들에게` = to those that have a walk of faith
- `하나님과의 관계이자 생명` = both life and a relationship with God
- `자체이다` = (the very thing) itself

I've heard `없어서는 안돼` like *it's not okay for something to be absent*, but I'm thrown by the position of `없어서는` in this sentence.

---

It seems to say that *a life of praise and worship, **if absent**, are a relationship with God and life itself* - which obviously must be wrong.

---

When placed into Google translate, it comes out just a little too well. Perhaps the engine either just got lucky, or it didn't process the ~없어서는

[image]

### Clarification and other examples of `없어서는` would be fruitful.

Comment: Just a little tip, NEVER use Google translate! For English-Korean, use Naver and for most other combinations use Papago. Google translate is VERY VERY inaccurate whether you need to say something in another language or translate something someones said to you. papago.naver.com was literally made for translations to and from korean and more often than not you always get perfect grammar and meaning in both languages

Comment: i'm still looking for **Clarification and other examples of 없어서는** with or without the key to the original (typo) mystery (solved in my solution below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure 없어서는 is a typo of 있어서는.

~에(게) 있어서는 is a common idiom meaning "when it comes to ..." or "to ..." as in "**그들에게 있어서는** 매우 중요한 문제였다 (**To them**, it was a very important matter)".

Comment: I think you're right I will double check Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

I was told it was supposed to have said

> 찬양과 예배의 삶은 신앙인들에게 없어서는 **안되는** 하나님과의 관계이자 생명 그 자체이다

[image]

Comment: It's interesting that while google and kakao both saw there are **two** terms for the word "life" in the sentence...papago missed it and mistakenly combined them (for a very large loss in meaning). @Kusnan

Answer (score 1):

있다 verb : be in place or state

1) 니가 여기 있어서는 (=있어선=있으면=머무르면=**stay**) 안된다. You
must leave here

네가 내 곁에 있어서 안심이다 I am safe because you are near to me.

2) 그것은 사회 발달에 있어서 (=발달에 있어=발달에서) 중요하다 It is
important **at** a social development

나에게 있어서 아버지는 중요하다=나에게 아버지는 중요하다 **To** me,
father is important.

@ That is, 1) is natural. But in 2), 에 있어서(=at) can be replaced
with 에서. There is some opinion that 에 있어서 in 2) is born when
we translate English sentence. Hence they recommend that we would
use 에서. But my habit may prefer 에 있어서.

Comment: 당신의 답은 없어서는 안된는 답이네요. 감사합니다!  -제이